# Embedded Vega is missing tooltips

Tags: charts, tooltip, vega

I have the following [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tester901/y8x3qmkL/), demonstrating a small Vega Bar chart:

```
<head>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vega@5"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="view"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var view;

    var chart = { Vega code removed for brevity - please check JSFiddle}

    render(chart);
    
    function render(spec) {
      view = new vega.View(vega.parse(spec), {
        renderer:  'canvas',  // renderer (canvas or svg)
        container: '#view',   // parent DOM container
        hover:     true       // enable hover processing
      });
      return view.runAsync();
    }
    
    
  </script>
</body>
```

If you copy the vega object into Vega Editor you get a tooltip when hovering over the chart elements.
Within the JSFiddle there is **no tooltip**.

Could someone please help me get a tooltip in the HTML-embedded version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been able to get the full functionality through using **vega-embed** with versions listed below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="vega-5.17.3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="vega-lite-4.17.0.min.js"></script>
  <script src="vega-embed-6.15.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="vis"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var spec = { Vega code removed for brevity - please check JSFiddle}
 vegaEmbed('#vis', spec).then(function(result) {
  }).catch(console.error);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```